# Execute a node script with from inside a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Strange question, but currently I have a script that I run from the terminal which requires a parameter. Normally I will run this by doing `node script.js param`, but now I want to run this script with the parameter from inside a JS file when the Express server loads.

The parameter is taken in and defined in the file like this:

`var param = process.argv[process.argv.length - 1];`

What is the best practice for making this file accessible elsewhere in my Node app and running it?

Comment: `require("script.js")`  file from other file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly following should work.

**script.js**

```
module.exports = function (params) {

console.log(params);

}
```

**main.js**

```
var param = process.argv[process.argv.length - 1];

require('./script')(param);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get param from another source when the script is required you can make a verification if the script is running directly from command line or it was required:

```
if (require.main === module) {
    var param = process.argv[process.argv.length - 1];
} else {
    var param = // get from other source. 
}
```